# Holonomy group of Enriques surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, holonomy

I expect that the holonomy group of an Enriques surface $S$ is $SU(2)\times C_2$. I think this can be proven by the fact that its double cover, which is a K3 surface, has the full $SU(2)$ holonomy, but I failed proving it. The holonomy group should be either $SU(2)$ or its $\pi_1(S)=C_2$-extension $SU(2)\times C_2$. Could someone help me prove or disprove this?

Comment: $U(2)$ is not a $C_2$ extension of $SU(2)$, though; unless you and I mean something different by the word extension.  $SU(2)$ is the kernel of the determinant map $U(2) \to U(1)$.

Comment: You are right. $U(2)$ should have been $SU(2)\times C_2$. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assume that you have endowed an Enriques surface $S$ with a Ricci-flat Kähler metric $g$.  The holonomy $H$ of $g$ cannot be contained in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ because the canonical bundle of $S$ is not trivial (though its square is trivial).  Meanwhile, the identity component of $H$ has to be equal to $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ because this is the holonomy of the (simply-connected, non-product) K3 surface that is the double cover of $S$ endowed with one of its Ricci-flat Kähler metrics.  The fundamental group of $S$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so $H$ must be a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-extension of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ that lies inside $\mathrm{U}(2)$.  There is only one of these, namely the group consisting of those matrices in $\mathrm{U}(2)$ with determinant $\pm1$, so this must be $H$.

N.B.: $H$ is not isomorphic to $\mathrm{SU}(2)\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.  In the latter, the set of elements that satisfy $a^2=1$ has $4$ members: $(I_2,1),(-I_2,1),(I_2,-1),(-I_2,-1)$,  while, in the former, the set of matrices satisfying $A^2=I_2$ consists of two points, $\pm I_2$, together with the $2$-sphere consisting of the elements of the form $iJ$ where $J$ lies in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and satisfies $J^2 = - I_2$.

Comment: @Dr. Bryant Thanks you very much for the answer. I do not understand how you conclude that the identity component of the holonomy is $SU(2)$. As to $H$, you are totally right.

Comment: @DavidK.:  Oh.  I am relying on the Berger classification of holonomy for this:  We know that the identity component of the holonomy must be a subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ and, by Berger, we also know that the only connected proper subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ that can be the holonomy of a $4$-manifold is the identity subgroup, which can only happen if the metric $g$ is flat, which is clearly not possible.

Comment: @Dr. Bryant Thank you very much for the clarification. I am not familiar with the Berger classification. I will take a close look at it. I appreciate your kind reply.